# ¿Qué significan los operadores <=?

Tags: javascript

```
(d < 0) && (d = -d);
return d <= t;
```

Qué significa

```
 (d < 0) && (d = -d);
```

Hasta donde yo los usaba, el `&&` *para comprobación o para devolver 2 cosas*, pero acá, es como que estuviera haciendo un `if` en la parte de `d < 0` , pero en verdad no hay ningún `if`, entonces  ¿Qué hace?

¿Qué es `<=` ?

Comment: ¿Qué es `<=`? _menor o igual_ ,  en su pregunta `&&` se sigue usando para una comprobación lógica pero está vez anidada , el `return` no parece tener ámbito correcto. No queda clara esa parte.

Comment: Significa `if(d<0){ d = -d; return ...}`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lo que hace

```
 (d < 0) && (d = -d)
```

Es simplemente asignar a `d` el valor absoluto del valor original. Es decir, sería equivalente a:

```
d = Math.abs(d)
```

El operador `&&` además de realizar la operación lógica AND tiene un segundo efecto: el segundo operando no se evalúa si el primero es falso.

Por lo tanto qué está haciendo el código:

Si se cumple la primera condición (`d` es menor que 0 y por lo tanto es negativo) se ejecuta la segunda parte (`d = -d`) y por lo tanto el valor de `d` queda como positivo.

Sin embargo, si no se cumple la primera condición (`d` es 0 o mayor que 0 y por tanto es un 0 o valor positivo) no se hace nada. Y por lo tanto `d` queda con el valor original 0 o positivo.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#calcular').click(function(){
    var valor = $('#valor').val();
    console.log('Valor: ' + valor);
    console.log('Math.abs(valor): ' + Math.abs(valor));
    (valor < 0) && (valor = -valor);
    console.log('(valor < 0) && (valor = -valor): ' + valor);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Valor: <input type="number" id="valor" value="-5">
<button id="calcular">Calcular</button>
```

Answer (score 11):

#### Observa este codigo:

```js
function comprobar(){
  return (1 > 0);
}

if (comprobar()) {
  console.log("1 ES MAYOR QUE 0");
} else {
  console.log("1 NO ES MAYOR QUE 0")
}
```

#### Que encontramos de extraño?

Esta instruccion puede tornarse algo confusa:

```
return (1 > 0);
```

#### Que ocurre en esta instruccion?

Se evalua la condicion y se retorna su resultado, sease VERDADERO o FALSO.

#### Hasta aqui todo bien pero...

Este tipo de comprobaciones las podemos anidar con los operadores **(&&)** y **(||)**, e igual, podra hacerse un retorno del resultado de la condicion.

#### Por ejemplo

```js
function comprobar(){
  return (1 > 0) && (2 < 4);
}

if (comprobar()) {
  console.log("1 ES MAYOR QUE 0 Y 2 MENOR QUE 4");
} else {
  console.log("1 NO ES MAYOR QUE 0, 2 NO ES MENOR QUE 4");
}
```

---

He hecho un *posible ejemplo* del ejemplo que nos has mostrado:

```js
function comprobacion(d, t){
  (d < 0) && (d = -d);
  return d <= t;
}

console.log(comprobacion(1, 2));
```

Si ejecutamos el codigo, el operador `<=` no es mas que el operador "Menor o Igual que", lo que ocurriria en esa sentencia es que se retornara `true` o `false` dependiendo del resultado de esa comparacion, pero despues de el se encuentra una asignacion:

```
(d = -d);
```

En este caso, la linea sobre la que consultas:

```
(d < 0) && (d = -d);
```

Realmente esta haciendo una **comparacion y una asignacion**, algo como:

> SI d es MENOR que 0 ASIGNO el VALOR NEGATIVO AL NUMERO d.

Lo cual te devolvera el numero **POSITIVO** (por aquello de la doble negacion). *Recuerda que los numeros negativos, son aquellos que son menores a 0*.

Como por ejemplo:

```js
var X = -5;

(X < 0) && (X = -X);

console.log("El valor de X es:" + X);
```

Puedes encontrar mas informacion sobre los **[operadores en Javascript.](http://librosweb.es/libro/javascript/capitulo_3/operadores.html)**

Comment: Me podrias dar documentación? y no me explicaste la parte de  d < 0 , ya que no era return esa parte

Answer (score 2):

La expresión `(b < 0) && (b = -b)` esta verificando que si el valor de `b` es negativo entonces lo convertirá a su valor positivo. La sentencia `(b < 0)` actúa como un `if` evaluando todo lo que se encuentre dentro los paréntesis y si el resultado da verdadero se ejecuta el código que se encuentre después de los `&&` en el caso contrario devuelve falso.

La siguiente expresión se podría representar de la siguiente manera:

```js
function Aa(b, t) {
  // si b es un valor negativo osea menor a 0 se va ejecutar el codigo que este dentro de los "{}"
  // y si no lo es osea que es mayor a 0 entonces la variable b se queda con el valor original que tenia.
    
  if(b < 0) { // esto es igual a decir (b < 0) && (b = -b).
    b = -b
  }
  
  /* 
   * si b es menor o igual a t esto retorna true de lo contrario retorna false.
   * el operador ( <= ) significa que si el valor que esta antes es "menor o igual" que el valor que esta después es un caso verdadero y si no lo es entonces es falso.
  */
  
  return b <= t // esto retorna true o false 
  
}

console.log(Aa(-1, 2)) // true
console.log(Aa(4, 2))  // false
console.log(Aa(2, 2))  // true
```

Este tipo de setencias normalmente se utilizan cuando quieres retornar dos valores pero que solo tengan dos posibles resultados en este caso si aplicaremos esto en una función diciéndole lo siguiente:

```js
function Aa(b) {
  return (b < 0) && (b = -b)
  // Esto es lo mismo que utilizar el operador ternario:
  // return (b < 0) ? b = -b : false
}

console.log(Aa(-2)) // 2
console.log(Aa(2))  // false
```

Comment: Es bueno recordar y recalcar que los operadores lógicos `&&` y `||` no tienen por qué devolver un `Boolean`. Ambos convierten implícitamente los operandos a tipo `Boolean` para comprobar si cumple la condición, pero el valor devuelto es el resultado de las expresiones, no la conversión. P ej: `(b<0) && (b = -b)` Si la primera expresión evalúa a `false`, devuelve `false` (el resultado de una expresión de comparación es un `Boolean`); en cambio, si la primera expresión evalúa a `true` devuelve el resultado de la segunda (expresión con operador de asignación que devuelve el valor asignado).